# Activity to Fragment transition with slide menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, slide

I am trying to make an App on android. I have made the slide in menu bar like the one shown in the the example picture below. The blue bar.It is my main activity. Now what I want is that my every screen should show the same menu options. Not those with the back button. How do I do that? 
Right now I have a main activity which initialized the slide menu and menu has options. Its showing the Home screen which is a fragment. From Home screen using a button i move to my next screen which is of a barcode scanner and is a new Activity and has no slide menu. From this screen I move to a new screen which shows the results of the scanner screen, and is a new activity,which were put and passed through intent extra.

Now I want the result screen to also show the same slide menu as it was on the home page.

All my other screens are also made as activities.

How do I do it?

Main Slide menu Activity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
RelativeLayout drawerPane;
ListView lvNav;

List<NavItem> listNavItems;
List<Fragment> listFragments;

ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerPane = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_pane);
    lvNav = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.nav_list);

    listNavItems = new ArrayList<NavItem>();
    listNavItems.add(new NavItem("Home", "MyHome page",
            R.drawable.ic_action_home));
    listNavItems.add(new NavItem("Settings", "Change something",
            R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
```

Home screen code:

```
 public class MainActivityFrag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageButton scan;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_screen, container, false);
    // setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
    scan=(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.scanBtn);
    scan.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}


public void ScanBarcode(View view) {
    Intent newScreen = new Intent("com.aaa.fyp.SimpleScannerActivity");
    // finish();

    startActivity(newScreen);
    //  finish();
}
```

Barcode scan screen code:

```
   @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        // Do something with the result here
        AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
        Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
        String gmail = null;

        for(Account account: list)
        {
            if(account.type.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google"))
            {
                gmail = account.name;
                break;
            }
        }

        Toast.makeText(SimpleScannerActivity.this,gmail,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.v(TAG, rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
       // Toast.makeText(SimpleScannerActivity.this, rawResult.toString() + "  WOW scanned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       // Toast.makeText(SimpleScannerActivity.this, rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v(TAG, rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)
        //Intent scanScreenResult= new Intent("com.aaa.fyp.ScanResultScreen");

        Intent nextScreen = new Intent("com.aaa.fyp.ScanResultScreen");
        nextScreen.putExtra("barcode",rawResult.toString());
        nextScreen.putExtra("format", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
       finish();
        startActivity(nextScreen);
```

Scan result screen showing the results from the scan screen in a new activity. This is the page where I want the the same slide menu:

```
public class ScanResultScreen extends SimpleScannerActivity {

ImageView scanned;
TextView bc;
TextView f;
String Barcode;
String format;

TextView d;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.scan_screen_with_button);
    // setContentView(R.layout.scan_screen_with_button);

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.scanScreenWithButton);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    setContentView(layout);
    Intent prevScreen = getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent

    Barcode=prevScreen.getStringExtra("barcode");
    bc= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.barcode_label);
    bc.setText(Barcode);

    format=prevScreen.getStringExtra("format");
    f=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.format_label);
    f.setText(prevScreen.getStringExtra("format").toString());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create `BaseActivity` which is extended by your other activites. In `BaseActivity` create side menu so it can be used by other activities which extend this activity.

Just to mention that having drawer menu (side menu) inside of "Detail view" activity is not good practice (user experience). Read about providing ancestral and temporal navigation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal.html).

Forexcanging data between your activites you can use this :

Activity1 setting data

```
//Get the intent parameters and pass it to aragment
Class data=new Class();
//Set data attributes
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity2.class);
detailsIntent.putExtra("data", data);
getActivity().startActivity(detailsIntent);
```

Activity2 getting data in onCreate() method :

```
Class data = ((Class) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data"));
//Use data in new activity
```

In your case :

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(ScanResultScreen.class);
nextScreen.putExtra("barcode",rawResult.toString());
nextScreen.putExtra("format", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
getActivity().startActivity(nextScreen);
```

In your ScanResultScreen activity do this :

```
String barcode = getIntent().getStringExtra("barcode");
String format = getIntent().getStringExtra("format");
```

Comment: Yes I did. What I am also doing is sending data from one activity to another as well. How to go about it?

Comment: You can send/retrieve your data with Bundle.

Comment: i am new to android. Can you explain it to me with a lil code? My main activity code is given above. which creates the slide menu. Should I extend all my activities with it? and how to change the intent code in the above given method of HandleResult to Bundle to send data to ScanResultScreen

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it as correct. Extending other activites depends on your activity requirements.